# Illegal 'use strict' directive in function with non-simple parameter list

Tags: vuejs3, staging, zegocloud

Illegal 'use strict' directive in function with non-simple parameter list

[See Image of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Z8Kt.png)

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal 'use strict' directive in function with non-simple parameter list
> at ./node_modules/.pnpm/localforage@1.10.0/node_modules/localforage/dist/localforage.js (index.bb2c0682.js:25076:304)
> at **webpack_require** (index.bb2c0682.js:81285:298)
> at eval (ZegoExpressWebRTM.js:1:164)
> at eval (ZegoExpressWebRTM.js:1:311)
> at ./node_modules/.pnpm/zego-express-engine-webrtm@1.23.0/node_modules/zego-express-engine-webrtm/ZegoExpressWebRTM.js (index.bb2c0682.js:80907:350)
> at **webpack_require** (index.bb2c0682.js:81285:298)
> at eval (ZegoExpressWebRTC.js:1:41)
> at eval (ZegoExpressWebRTC.js:1:234)
> at ./node_modules/.pnpm/zego-express-engine-webrtc@2.24.0/node_modules/zego-express-engine-webrtc/ZegoExpressWebRTC.js (index.bb2c0682.js:80898:299)
> at **webpack_require** (index.bb2c0682.js:81285:298)

This error appears on the staging environment of my vue js app that uses ZegoCloud Prebuilt UIKit

My steps for deploying:

> `npm run build` on my local development branch
>
> `commit and push` on the development branch
>
> `git pull` on my server

Info about server setup:
`EC2 Instance - Ubuntu`

The error appears only on the staging environment but not on the local development. If anyone can help, thank you!

Comment: Please paste the error as text instead of an image.

Comment: Okay will edit the post and put the errors as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue in my staging environment.

I encountered errors when running the ZegoCloud package version 1.8.2 in my staging environment, and the reason behind these errors remains unknown. If anyone has insights or potential solutions for this issue, please kindly share them as an answer below.

To resolve the problem, I successfully downgraded the zegocloud prebuilt package from version 1.8.2 to 1.5.2. It appears that the package version 1.8.2 experiences problems related to the "use strict" directives.

Here are the steps I followed to perform the downgrade:

> `Edit the package.json file:`

Change the line:

> from: `"@zegocloud/zego-uikit-prebuilt": "^1.8.2"`
>
>  to: `"@zegocloud/zego-uikit-prebuilt": "1.5.2"`

Run the command:

 `npm run build`

`Commit and push the changes.`

`Pull the updated code from the server.`

Note: I have not tested the Zegocloud package versions between 1.5.2 and 1.8.2, so it is possible that alternative versions within that range may also resolve the issue.